# I have a problem with Bootstrap background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

This is my html code, it works but it gives me a problem with the body background-color of the bootstrap, 'cause I don't want to have a background color. How can I eliminate it? Can someone help me?
I put an image of the result.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdF9E.jpg)
[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aEm5.png)

I searched on the internet but, it didn't help. It's for a school project.

Comment: Please add a code snippet with both HTML and CSS

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 1):

You can override body CSS styles:

```css
body {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I think boostrap 3.4.1 does not have this class?

Comment: You are correct. Apologies. I didn't expect a question on such an old version.